# Make css :hover only affect parent element

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-class

In css, how can I stop the `:hover` event being triggered in a parent element when a child event is hovered, so that it only gets triggered when the parent itself gets hovered? In this case my child element is actually positioned outside it's parent element with absolute positioning, so it's a bit weird when the parent changes when the child gets hovered.

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4VwtU/) to illustrate the problem.

*Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4VwtU/4/) of the used solution to my example.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a pure css solution (even two in fact) but both come at a cost.

1. You can add pointer-events:none; to your child element - but it will not respond to it's own hover styles either. [Pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/pointer-events) unfortunately are not supported in IE below version 11 (http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events).
2. Wrap content of your parent element (apart from positioned child) in another one (thats the cost of this method) and apply hover styles to this wrapper.

Examples of both methods [here](http://jsfiddle.net/theLitek/3CUfa/1/).

```
.parent-2,
.parent { position:relative; background:#ddd; width:100px; height:100px; }
.parent:hover { background:blue; }
.child { position:absolute; top:0; left:130px; width:100px; height:50px; border:1px solid blue; pointer-events:none; }
/* doesn't work in opera and ie */


.content { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:0;}
.content:hover { background:blue; }
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply: don't nest your `#inner` `div` inside. Little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/Va5NN/). Note that I added:

```
html, body {
    position: relative;
}
```

Which is necessary in this case.

**Edit:** in case you insist on having it nested, a bit of JavaScript is necessary. Here's a sample:

```
var inn = document.getElementById("inner"), outt = document.getElementById("holder");
outt.onmouseover = function() {
   this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 162, 232)"; /*I like this color :)*/
}
outt.onmouseout = function() {
   this.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}
inn.onmouseover = function(ev) {
   ev.stopPropagation();
}
```

(This would be shorter if written using jQuery, but the idea is the same).

Here's a demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/HRzxk/).

Comment: I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: @BoltClock Well, I've tried without it; apparently `html` and `body` don't get `position: relative;` by default.

Comment: The element needs to be nested in it's parent

Comment: @CupOfTea696 Why, precisely? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Abody97: Now that is bizarre. They don't get it by default, but an absolutely-positioned element should still be relative to the viewport if none of its ancestors are relative.

Comment: @BoltClock `html` and `body` don't always expand to fill the viewport, you know. In this case, they're only becoming as large as needed to fit `#holder`.

Comment: @Abody97: Oh, I get it - the top/left/bottom/right offsets are missing, which may be the issue. I've never understood how `auto` works for those properties.

Comment: Yea I know I could solve this with jQuery but I was actually wondering if there's a CSS only solution.

Comment: @CupOfTea696 Probably not. `:hover` states in CSS are propagated -- no real way of preventing them. Although, I must point out, the snippet in my answer doesn't use jQuery :)

Comment: Well, you could add a transparent element over the child, but that feels a bit dirty to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a bit of JavaScript to stop the event from bubbling.  Take a look at this example:

[css :hover only affect top div of nest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679283/css-hover-only-affect-top-div-of-nest)

Comment: Yea, but I was actually wondering if there's a CSS only solution.