# Newbie jQuery ancestory navigation issue

Tags: jquery, html

Apologies for the basic question but I am trying to add a hover state to a navigation list and cannot seem to work out how to have a hover state over a child without affecting the parent `<li>`. The parent `<li>` is technically being hovered over too. I am aware that `.add/removeClass()` is more ideal but for my testing, it was just easier with `.attr()`.

So far I have got:

I have a jsfiddle set up at http://jsfiddle.net/gSPkj/ but below is the code-

HTML-

```
<div id="sidebarNav">
<ul>
    <li class="parent"><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="page4.html">Page 4</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="child"><a href="subpage_of_4-2.html">Subpage of 4 - 1</a></li>
            <li class="child"><a href="subpage_of_4-2.html">Subpage of 4 - 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery -

```
    $("#sidebarNav li.parent").hover(function(){
$(this).attr("style","background:#123de1;color:#eb9028;");
},function(){
$(this).attr("style","background:#fff;color:#000;");
});
$("#sidebarNav li.child").hover(function(){
$(this).attr("style","background:#123de1;color:#eb9028;");
$(this).parents(".parent").attr("style","background:#fff;color:#000;");
},function(){
$(this).attr("style","background:#fff;color:#000;");
});
```

Comment: Have a look at this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327711/jquery-hover-event-with-nested-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to target the anchors, and then find the closest li element to attach the styles. I'd do it like this:

```
$("#sidebarNav li > a").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('li').css({
        background: (e.type == 'mouseenter' ? '#123de' : '#fff'),
        color:  (e.type == 'mouseenter' ? '#eb9028' : '#000')
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gSPkj/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS only

```
a:hover {
    background: #123de1;
    color: #eb9028;
}
```

Modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gSPkj/3/)

If you really need Javascript, you can use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$("#sidebarNav li.child").hover(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).attr('style','background:#123de1;color:#eb9028;');
},function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).attr('style','background:#000;color:#fff;');
});
```

Although this still has issues, when moving from the child to the parent or backwards.

Modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gSPkj/6/)